# is it possible that the code skip continue?

Tags: java, oop, if-statement, continue

Is there any case that the program will skip `continue`? This is the code:

```
     while(/*something*/){
           if(/*something*/){
                while(true) {
                    //do something

                }
                System.out.print("Hello");
                continue;
            }
//do something2
    }
```

I would put my whole code but it's very long to trace. i want to know if there is a known cases that the `continue` will be skipped. My program enters the big while-loop, enters if-statement but sometimes it doesn't continue and skip to `//do something2` . There is no breaks or anything like that.

Comment: `//do something` ==> `break;` ?

Comment: Why would you think that there are cases it wouldn't? What are you trying to accomplish? If you put any control flow statement before it will not be hit.

Comment: Yes, if there is a `break` statement inside your `\\do something` block.

Comment: @August only break could lead to "Hello" being printed.

Comment: I just updated the question and the code. Please check

Comment: @MikeKobit I just updated the question. maybe it is clear now

Comment: @hzjw show a complete code that reproduce the behaviour you are observing. Otherwise people can only guess.

Answer (score 3):

`while(true)` will always continue if the end of the loop is reached. You can stop the while loop by using `break`:

```
while(true) {
    //doSomething

    if (myCondition) 
        break;
}
```

If myCondition is true, you will break out of the while loop.